# Button in XML much bigger than in PNG

Tags: android, xml, png

Someone made a design for my application. He sent me all the layers separated from each other (buttons, background etc.) He first sent me the whole layout in a .png file and a few days ago everything separated (in the same size), but when I add a button its much bigger than in the png file he sent me first (even though they are the same sizes). Ive 2 screens where you can see the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmmRC.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQgTR.png

So my designer took the button from the first .png (first picture) and he cut it out and I added it into my design (second picture). Anyone an idea how I could get the same size button(s) from the first .png file correctly into my design?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should make yourself familiar with the way Android is working with different screen resolutions and pixel densities etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your designer should hand you the image in multiple sizes. 
He should make his total design in multiple canvas sizes that match the phones you'd like to support. If you like to support a great deal of devices, you can use Google's size and DPI buckets as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

A less proper way could be adding a hard size in your xml to the .

If the screenshots represent the real design, it would probably be best if you take a look at creating this in XML with drawables instead, since its very basic and this would save your app some space.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing it this way - see my answer below. Your response, while it would support devices of different screen density, may encounter problems with screens of different size/ratio, as the pixel values and the images would be hardcoded into the app. To make an app that's worth releasing, you should hardcode as little as possible, and that includes image sizes

Comment: Hey Matt, as I stated i'm not a big fan of hardcoding the sizes neither. It is however the easiest way and since the thread starter seems to be a beginner it might help him to be able to continue like this for a while until he has more experience. You're right though that in the end, you shouldn't hardcode the sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a png as your button image, Android has the 9-patch system built in to handle resizing of graphics: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch, which is similar in style to how some website backgrounds are drawn.

Android also has it's own 9-patch creator bundled with the sdk:  http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html, so it's easy enough to edit your friend's png files, then apply the 9-patch to the button.

You then change the button size as you need in your app, and the background will scale with your button

Comment: How does this work? I tried it but can't make the button smaller.

Comment: You resize the button yourself in xml, with whatever layout you're using. The 9-patch will then scale itself to fit your button object